# openCV stereoCalibrate - Assertion failed (D1.empty() || (D1.total() == 4))

Tags: java, opencv

I'm using openCV's `calibrateCamera()` to retrieve `distCoeffs` that I want to use as input for `stereoCalibrate()`. But calling stereoCalibrate() gives me the following error message:

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (D1.empty() || (D1.total() == 4)) in stereoCalibrate

Debugging tells me that D1.total() is 5 and that it's not empty. I didn't modify `distCoeffs` (D1) so I thought it would be suitable as input parameter for `stereoCalibrate()` without further modification.

```
org.opencv.calib3d.Calib3d.calibrateCamera(objectPoints, cheesboardCornersList, chessboardImg.size(), intrMatrix1, distCoeffs1, rvecs1, tvecs1);

org.opencv.calib3d.Calib3d.calibrateCamera(objectPoints, cheesboardCornersList, chessboardImg.size(), intrMatrix2, distCoeffs2, rvecs2, tvecs2);

...

org.opencv.calib3d.Calib3d.stereoCalibrate(objectPoints, imagePoints1, imagePoints2, intrMatrix1, distCoeffs1, intrMatrix2, distCoeffs2, img1.size(), R, T, org.opencv.calib3d.Calib3d.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC);
```

(Java, openCV 3.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem with `stereoCalibrate()`.
But you may notice that `Calib3d` has another one version of `stereoCalibrate`.

```
public static double stereoCalibrate(java.util.List<Mat> objectPoints,
                                     java.util.List<Mat> imagePoints1,
                                     java.util.List<Mat> imagePoints2,
                                     Mat cameraMatrix1,
                                     Mat distCoeffs1,
                                     Mat cameraMatrix2,
                                     Mat distCoeffs2,
                                     Size imageSize,
                                     Mat R,
                                     Mat T,
                                     Mat E,
                                     Mat F)
```

[look here](http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.1.0/)

The difference is that this version of method also returns essential matrix `E` and fundamental matrix `F`.
This helped for me. I used JavaCV wrapper from [bytedeco](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv), but I think it doesn't matter - native methods are the same.